# Render is giving black and blank screen

Tags: rendering, animation

In my scene when I render animation or photo they just go by quick and produce black images. Can someone look at my file and help me fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it I went to Properties Panel> Render Tab> and under Post Processing Unchecked Sequencer.